# Dealing with a question that have no technical solution but may have in the future

Tags: discussion, answers

Suppose that a given product (tool, framework, etc.) is under development. At the moment a product is not supporting a feature which is related to a SO question, however there is a good chance to have a technical solution in the future.

How to deal with such a situation? Would it be better to:

1. Write a short comment that just confirms lack of reasonable solution / workaround?
2. Write rather an unsatisfactory but detailed answer pointing out the root-cause and technicalities?

---

To be more specific: I am going to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994955/eclipselink-mongodb-criteriaquery-on-embedded-field), however I am not sure how to deal with it properly.

Here are some additional notes I would like include in the answer:

- the problem is reproducible
- output from the log clearly states that the feature is currently not supported
- some technicalities related to the root-cause
- it seems there is no solution or satisfactory workaround at the moment
- the solution will most likely require creating a new issue against the product

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Saying it doesn't exist will get my approval, explaining why it doesn't will get my upvote. "It's not possible" is an invaluable answer if that is the case.

Comment: I'm not a MongoDB expert, but from the error message, it's not at all clear that this just isn't supported yet as opposed to an error in the user's code.  It's definitely helpful to explain that, particularly if you can provide evidence (a link to an issue, or a TODO comment in the code).

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom: actually the problem is related to EclipseLink; as for the rest of your comment - the same feature works perfectly with SQL databases but not with NoSQL ones (MongoDB in particular, didn't check the others as it's out of the question's scope). Did some debugging and I can point out a potential place in the code that leads to the error. From the other hand the ultimate evidence would be IMO to create an issue against the product and wait for a commiter's answer but it may take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you should post it as an answer because it provides valuable information about the solution (that it doesn't exist). I have seen such answers and they are upvoted by the community.
I suppose comments are for asking more details about the question.

Comment: Answer posted. Hopefully it will be useful for the community.